# Lynx Luminosity (Eclipse) error "The chosen operation is not currently available."

Tags: eclipse, lynxos

Clicking any item in the "Lynx" menu results in an Information popup box with the message "The chosen operation is not currently available."
Versions:

- Luminosity 5.1.0
- Eclipse 4.4.0

Seems to be the same problem with an Eclipse plugin not loading that is described in other issues such as this one: [Eclipse Neon + Maven = The chosen operation is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35370389/eclipse-neon-maven-the-chosen-operation-is-not-available) but so far I have not found a solution that fixes the problem in this case.